# How do I select only fields where the date is not entered?

Tags: database, ms-access

So I have this table:

[image: Table]

When I try with IsEmpty([Rented Books].[When Returned]) I don't get any results in the Query Design.

It also doesn't work with IsNull or Len.

Can somebody give me a hand on how to filter those?

Comment: which database you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

`Is Null` in the Criteria Field did the job. I didn't do it correctly before that.